# I have a problem in (checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener), I have x number of checkboxes, when I check more than one it doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I have a list of checkboxes in the RecyclerView, when I check more than one checkbox at a time it doesn't work and only the last clicked item get checked. Unchecking also is the same problem.

[image]

If I check, let's say (a) and then (b) later (c) and when I press back key and return to the list, only (c) got checked. Can anyone pinpoint the bug for me.

```
    checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilderStatus = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<String> newStatusList;;
    String txt = checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.getText().toString();
    if (b) {
    statusSplit = status.split("\n");
    newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));
    newStatusList.set(position, "1");

    for(String singleStatus: newStatusList){
    stringBuilderStatus.append(singleStatus);
    stringBuilderStatus.append("\n");
    }
    String statuses = stringBuilderStatus.toString();

    checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setText(lineThrough(txt));
    dbHelper.updateChecklist(id,statuses , content, DateTime.date(), DateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());

    }
    else {

    statusSplit = status.split("\n");
    newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));
    newStatusList.set(position, "0");

    stringBuilderStatus = new StringBuilder();
    for(String singleStatus: newStatusList){
    stringBuilderStatus.append(singleStatus);
    stringBuilderStatus.append("\n");
    }
    String statuses = stringBuilderStatus.toString();

    checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setText(txt);
    dbHelper.updateChecklist(id,statuses , content, DateTime.date(), DateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain what your code should do and does. And where is it that you check them when you come back?

Comment: @blackapps I want to check more than one checkbox at a time. Here if check ( a, b and c) item only the last item gets checked

Comment: @blackapps When I return to see if they are checked properly. If  want to check all these 4 checkboxes I need to check one checkbox, press back button and then return to check another item and because of that I need 4 times to check all the checkboxes, I have check one press back key and then check another press back key again until I finish checking them all an that is not what I want.

Comment: Dont understand a word. Why cant the user check four checkboxes? And if he closes the thing and comes back no one is checked as you are nowhere setting them back.